# How to add another field in connection with a ManyToManyField?

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

```
class Team(models.Model):
    college = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/',null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.college  

  class Athletics(Match):
        time = ?
        player = models.ManyToManyField(Player, related_name='player')
        game_level = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, choices=LEVEL_CHOICES) # like semi-final, final etc
        game_specific = models.CharField(max_length=256,null=True, choices=EVENT_CHOICES) #like Men's Shot Put or Men's Triple Jump etc

        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.game_level)
```

I am making an **Athletics** Sports Model for a sports tournament. I have an existing **Player** Model where I have listed players names and their teams. Now as you can see, I have added **player** field as ManyToManyField to choose for say *4-5* players match. Now I need finishing time for each player for judging who qualifies for the next round. Can it be possible to do this in this model only? Or I have to add another model? Help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an intermediate model between Player and Athletics to record information specific to the many-to-many relationship of the two models. Please read [Extra fields on many-to-many relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships).

```
class PlayeAthletics(models.Model):
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    athletics = models.ForeignKey(Athletics, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    time = models.IntegerField()

class Athletics(Match):
    player = models.ManyToManyField(Player, through='PlayerAthletics')
```